# Запуталась, ларьков, которых или которые

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Владельцы сувенирных ларьков на улице Московской в Ялте, которых администрация города хочет убрать с места торговли, обратились с жалобой к председателю городского совета

Answer (score 3):

"Которых" относилось бы к владельцам (согласование с одушевлённым сущ.) - вряд ли конкретно *их* хотят убрать, поэтому правильно: "**которые**" (согласуется с неодушевлённым "ларьки").

Comment: Это Крым, там всё что угодно сейчас может быть. Владельцев тоже убирают пачками. А на их месте растут новые. Другое дело, что газетах этот вариант обычно не освещается...

Comment: Тогда приходится признать возможность того, что администрация сделала владельцам предложение покинуть свою собственность, с намерением насильственной передачи её другим владельцам.

Comment: Во-первых, совсем не обязательно понимать именно так. Во-вторых, такие случаи там сейчас - сплошь и рядом. Собственность, правда, не забирают, а предлагают снести за свой счет и штрафуют неподчинившихся. Через неделю на том же месте появляются новые владельцы. Мог бы примеры назвать конкретные, но мне очень бы не хотелось уходить в сферы околополитические,

Answer (score 2):

Если администрация хочет убрать с места **владельцев**, то **которых**. 
А если **ларьки** - то **которые**.

А всего правильнее - переделать фразу. И не забывать про точку в конце.